# docker installed with brew fails on /var/run/docker.sock

Tags: docker, homebrew

I installed docker on my Mac, using brew:

```
$ brew install docker
```

Running docker with no arguments works fine and shows a list of commands, but running a search fails like this:

```
$ docker search riak

FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.17/images/search?term=riak: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

`docker images` fails the same way. How can I get this running?

Edit:
I ran

```
$ brew install boot2docker
$ boot2docker init
```

That failed with

```
error in run: Failed to initialize machine "boot2docker-vm": exit status 1
```

Hopefully this sheds some light on the situation:

```
$ boot2docker -v info
Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.5.0
Git commit: ccd9032
2015/03/09 12:48:51 executing: VBoxManage showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
{
    "Name": "boot2docker-vm",
    "UUID": "978c667c-9e7b-4026-823e-fa9ccde98a47",
    "Iso": "",
    "State": "running",
    "CPUs": 1,
    "Memory": 128,
    "VRAM": 8,
    "CfgFile": "/Users/issactrotts/VirtualBox VMs/boot2docker-vm/boot2docker-vm.vbox",
    "BaseFolder": "/Users/issactrotts/VirtualBox VMs/boot2docker-vm",
    "OSType": "",
    "Flag": 0,
    "BootOrder": null,
    "DockerPort": 0,
    "SSHPort": 0,
    "SerialFile": ""
}
```

Most likely DockerPort and SSHPort should not be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that brew installed [boot2docker](http://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/), as there does not appear to be any other supported, non-experimental way to run Docker on a Mac.  Following the instructions from that page, you need to run `boot2docker init; boot2docker start` and then, in every shell session in which you want to use any Docker commands, you have to run `$(boot2docker shellinit)` (The `$(...)` is required in order to execute the output of `shellinit`).

Comment: Nope, brew has a separate package for `boot2docker`. Now that I think about it, I don't think it makes sense to be running docker on Mac OS X for my situation. I'll see about using it from a virtual machine running Ubuntu instead.

Comment: `boot2docker init` failed with this message: `error in run: Failed to initialize machine "boot2docker-vm": exit status 1`. It looks like Docker isn't well supported on Mac right now.

Comment: The `docker` client runs well on a Mac, but the `docker` daemon must run on a Linux machine. The usual way to do this is with Virtualbox (via boot2docker), but any VM can work.

Comment: Docker daemon now exists for Mac, is installed using dmg: https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-mac